# Working around no lambdas in VS 2005

Tags: .net, vb.net, lambda

I have the following excerpt from some wonderful legacy code:

```
Private Sub SomeMethod()
    Dim deductibles As List(Of Integer) = GetDeductibles()    
    deductibles.RemoveAll(AddressOf LessThanMinDed)
EndSub
Private Function LessThanMinDed(ByVal i As Integer) As Boolean
    Return i < MinimumDeductible()
End Function
```

If you're a language snob, we can write it this way:

```
private void SomeMethod() {
    List<int> deductibles = GetDeductibles();    
    deductibles.RemoveAll(LessThanMinDed);
}
private bool LessThanMinDed(int i) {
    return i < MinimumDeductible();
}
```

`MinimumDeductible()` makes a database call. Is there a way to write this *without* writing something like `x = MinimumDeductible() : RemoveAll(Function(i) i < x)` (since lambdas aren't in this version of VB.NET) that will make a call to the database just once?

#### Solved (kind of):

Work around like so:

```
Public Class Foo
    Private CachedMinimum As Integer
    Private Sub SomeMethod()
        Dim deductibles As List(Of Integer) = GetDeductibles()
        Me.CachedMinimum = MinimumDeductible()
        deductibles.RemoveAll(AddressOf LessThanMinDed)
    End Sub
    Private Function LessThanMinDed(ByVal i As Integer) As Boolean
        Return i < CachedMinimum
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: As an aside, I would *strongly* advise you to try to move to a more recent version of VS. You can still target .NET 2.0 if you really have to from VS2013 or VS2015... but you can use a lot of the more recent language features.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I wish I was able to make these decisions... trust me, I would.

Comment: every lambda expression can be written in some For loops and conditions so write your own function with the available functions in the available .net Framework

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer really depends on the language. In C# 2, we didn't have lambda expressions but we *did* have anonymous methods... so you can write:

```
List<int> deductibles = GetDeductibles();    
deductibles.RemoveAll(delegate(int i) { return i < MinimumDeductible(); });
```

As far as I'm aware, there's no equivalent in the version of VB that shipped with VS 2005.

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas are just syntactic suger, at the end of the day.  They're always converted into named functions, so yes, it's is most certainly possible (you can always remove any lambda using adaptations of the following pattern).  Simply create a new object with the method that you need, and fields for the values you want to close over:

```
public class MyComparer
{
    private int value;
    public MyComparer(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public bool LessThanMinDed(int i)
    {
        return i < value;
    }
}
```

You can now write:

```
var comparer = new MyComparer(MinimumDeductible())
deductibles.RemoveAll(comparer.LessThanMinDed);
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean there are no lambdas in "VS 2005" (presumably you mean C# 2.0)? The syntax is just different!

```
int min = MinimumDeductible();

deductibles.RemoveAll(delegate (int i) {
    return i < min;
});
```

Comment: That's not a lambda, it's an anonymous method.

Comment: Those aren't lambda expressions - they're anonymous methods. Yes, they're both ways of creating delegates "inline", but if you look for "lambda" in the C# 2 spec you won't find it.

Comment: @JonSkeet The term "lambda function" exists outside the C# specs as well, and that thing is a lambda function no matter how you look at it.

Comment: When you're using a particular technology, I think it makes sense to stick to the terminology of that technology. The term "lambda expression" has a very specific meaning in C# - and one which the OP clearly intended - so I think it's a bad idea to muddy the waters by using it for something different. If you had said "closures" instead, that would be a different matter.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen, great answer, but unfortunately the code is written in VB.NET so I'm not able to use it.

Comment: @JosephNields: Hm. I guess my brain must've automatically ignored that part. There's free conversion tools available though!

Comment: @JosephNields: Anyways, luckily lambda functions or JonSkeet Methods or whatever you want to call them are all just syntactic sugar, and if you look at Servy's answer you can see what they essentially do on the inside. And that is surely supported in VB as well.

Answer (score 0):

1) I would try to solve it already on the DB. As you state MinimumDeductible comes from a database I guess GetDeductibles(..) could also come from the same DB and then I would simply create an SQL-View like

```
SELECT * FROM Deductibles ApplicationSettings 
WHERE Deductibles.Amount >= ApplicationSettings.MinimumDeductible;
```

And in the application select the already filtered view.

2) If that's not possible I would not use any Remove operation to solve the issue. If you use a remove on a list, the item must be found first which means if you have 10'000 items there must by average 5000 rows be compared until the item is found (as a list does not support hashcodes). Better you copy the items in a single loop and re-assign the result to the previous variable, something like that:

```
    Private Sub SomeMethod()
        Dim deductibles As List(Of Integer) = GetDeductibles()
        Dim minimum As Int32 = MinimumDeductible()
        deductibles = GetFilteredDeductibles(deductibles, minimum)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function GetFilteredDeductibles(rawDeductibles As List(Of Int32), minimumValue As Int32) As List(Of Int32)
        Dim result As New List(Of Int32)(rawDeductibles.Count)
        For Each myValue As Int32 In rawDeductibles
            If (myValue >= minimumValue) Then
                result.Add(myValue)
            End If
        Next
        result.TrimExcess()
        Return result
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is just a list of about 10 items max so it doesn't matter too much that it's iterating over the loop. It can get expensive when there are ten calls to the DB, though. I'm just going to keep the changes client-side (what I did) since it is a bit easier of a change to make with our systems.